# Rails callback - creating :on_login callback for a user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails provides a great feature that is model callback. These callbacks matches steps of an Active record object life cycle : after_save, before_validation, etc...

Therefore I'm wondering if we could has specific callbacks. For instance, :`after_login`, :`before_login`, :`after_logout`, ... for an user model would be great. How would one do that ?

There's the obvious way : inside your controller. Is there another one ?

Answer (score 0):

It's really very specific to your system, like how your user is logged or not.

You need to do yourself this callback. You can use the ActiveSupport::Callback to do that. You can made some feature request on your Authentication plugin.